# Onde esta definido o macro LITTLE_ENDIAN_HOST e como ele se comporta?

Tags: c, c++

Depois de finalmente entender como funciona a decodificação de opcodes com um projeto de um emulador de CHIP-8 eu resolvi voltar a um projeto antigo meu, um emulador de Gameboy, então comecei a implementar a CPU e seus registradores, a CPU do gameboy é semelhante a o 8080 e ao z80, o gameboy possui 6 registradores de 16-Bits sendo que a maioria é formado pela junção de 2 registradores de 8-Bits como indicado por [esta documentação](http://gbdev.gg8.se/files/docs/mirrors/pandocs.html#cpuregistersandflags).

Cheguei a um momento que precisei decrementar o registrador B que seria a extremidade mais alta de BC, pensei em usar o operador shift bit mas provavelmente iria apagar o valor de C, então conversando em um grupo do discord relacionado a desenvolvimento do gameboy de como eu poderia fazer isso um membro me apresentou o seguinte código:

```
    typedef union RegPair{

        std::uint16_t value;
        struct byte{

#ifndef LITTLE_ENDIAN_HOST
            std::uint8_t l, h;
#else
            std::uint8_t h, l;
#endif // !LITTLE_ENDIAN_HOST


        }b;

    }RegPair;

    struct Registers {

        RegPair AF, BC, DE, HL;

        std::uint16_t SP;    // Stack Pointer
        std::uint16_t PC;    // Program Counter

    };
```

Isso foi até fácil de entender, como value tem o tipo mais significativo na união então h e l assumiriam parte deste valor, mas a questão é `LITTLE_ENDIAN_HOST` certamente isso se refere ao tipo de extremidade da máquina, o que não entendo é:

Macros são para o compilador e não para o código, como eu verifiquei que minha maquina é Little Endian então o programa seria montado como little endian, então ele executaria em um computador Big Endian?

E onde esta a definição deste macro? Pesquisei no google mas só acho trechos de código mas nenhum site explicando a definição dele, em que cabeçalho ele esta definido etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LITTLE_ENDIAN_HOST` certamente é inerente a algum projeto específico e indica se o programa está sendo compilado em uma arquitetura `little-endian`, e não faz parte do padrão `C`.

É uma técnica bem comum para se manter uma boa [`portabilidade`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portabilidade_(inform%C3%A1tica)) do código, ou seja, permitindo que um mesmo código possa ser compilado e executado em diferentes ambientes e arquiteturas.

Certamente `LITTLE_ENDIAN_HOST` é definido pelo usuário durante a etapa de compilação do código/projeto.

Trechos condicionais do tipo:

```
#ifndef LITTLE_ENDIAN_HOST
            std::uint8_t l, h;
#else
            std::uint8_t h, l;
#endif // !LITTLE_ENDIAN_HOST
```

Decidem como será a implementação/comportamento do programa dependendo da [`Endianess`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) da arquitetura na qual ele será executado, e portanto, não tem efeito em tempo de execução.

Comment: Bom, se é definido no projeto então essa condição não afetaria já que sempre será chamado else correto?

Comment: No caso, o `else` seria uma compilação para arquitetura `little-endian`.